# TableView.reloadData() is not working ? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am developing a Quiz App which fetches questions from a JSON. I have already used reloadData for TableView many times & worked as expected. But now I am fetching Questions using Alamofire & saving it in a Array & fetching the Questions from the Array.

But it returns Array is Out of Index.

How can i Display the First item of the Array in the first Cell ?

**VC**

```
class ExamController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Exam: UITableView!

    var CourseID : String!
    var EID : String!
    var EName : String!
    var ET : String!

    var QArray : [String] = []

    var progress = GradientCircularProgress()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progress.show(style:MyStyle())
        // JUST TRIED
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.getQuestions()
            // DO SOMETHING ON THE MAINTHREAD
            self.Exam.reloadData()
        })

        self.Exam.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.Exam.tableFooterView?.hidden = true
    }

    func getQuestions(){

        if ET == "CHAPTER" {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wis.com/index.php/capp/chapter_questions_details/\(CourseID)/\(EID)/10")
                .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                    println(data)
                    let json = JSON(data!)
                    let catCount = json.count
                    for index in 0...catCount-1 {
                        let q = json[index]["QUESTION"].string
                        self.QArray.append(q!)
                        println(self.QArray)
                    }

            }

            self.progress.dismiss()
            self.Exam.reloadData()

        } else if ET == "FA" {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wis.com/index.php/capp/fa_questions_by_course_id/\(CourseID)/\(EID)")
                .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                    println(data)
                    let json = JSON(data!)
                    let catCount = json.count
                    for index in 0...catCount-1 {
                        let q = json[index]["QUESTION"].string
                        self.QArray.append(q!)
                        println(self.QArray)
                    }

            }
                        self.progress.dismiss()
                        self.Exam.reloadData()
    }
}

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            let cell = self.Exam.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Question") as! QuestionCell

            cell.Questionlabel?.text = QArray[0]
            return cell

        }
        else
        {
            let cell = self.Exam.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Option") as! OptionCell

            cell.Optionlabel?.text = "Option"
            return cell

        }
    }
```

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` must return the number of items in the data source dynamically not a static value

Comment: Put a `println` statement in the places where you call `reloadData`.  I'm guessing the call to reload is happening before your data is returned.  The log should show you the order of calls.

Comment: @vadian my Array has over 100 Questions. But i need only 5 rows in my TableView

Comment: @PhillipMills The Table View loads first before my Alamofire request completes :(

Comment: for feature please use `Code convention` and name u're variables with lower case char.
Like `aVariable`, not `Variable`.

in ure case `exam` or `aExam`. not `Exam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload your tableview inside `Alamofire` block

And so it will look like

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wis.com/index.php/capp/chapter_questions_details/\(CourseID)/\(EID)/10")
            .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                println(data)
                let json = JSON(data!)
                let catCount = json.count
                for index in 0...catCount-1 {
                    let q = json[index]["QUESTION"].string
                    self.QArray.append(q!)
                    println(self.QArray)
                }
        self.progress.dismiss()
        self.Exam.reloadData()
  }
```

and yes ofcourse, as per given answers and comments,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.QArray?.count ?? 0 // will return 0 rows if QArray is empty
}
```

This may help!

Comment: The Problem is that my QArray has over 100 items. But I just want the number of rows to be 5. How can i do this ?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I am not using any database

Comment: Then from where data is coming? And what happens if you apply my solution with numberOfrows = 5?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this UI http://i.imgur.com/xUGtMU9.png. I am getting the Questions from a JSON through API. But I have to show only a single Question in my Table view followed by four options from my answer Array.

Comment: Ok. Your request url says your api is in php. I think you need to use `LIMIT` clause in your query to get limited data everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Use dispatch queue to call your completion handler in .responseJSON , and from there update your UI .

E.G.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, postEndpoint, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in 

    // Do something...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Update your UI here
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it s helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to put the reload into the completion handler so that you have data when you try to update the UI.

To be safe (in case of other calls to reload), you can also guard your return value in `numberOfRowsInSection` by checking whether there are at least 5 items in `QArray`.