# async function in swift does not run after

Tags: ios, json, swift, dispatch-async

I try to populate my TableView with information that i get from a JSON
But already on numberOfRowsInSection it does not work

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let getVideoCount = Alamofire.request(.GET, APICall).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["items"].arrayObject {
                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
                print(self.arrRes.count) //runs after
            })
        }

        getVideoCount.resume()
        print(self.arrRes.count) //runs first
        return arrRes.count

    }
```

i try with the dispatch_async to run the JSON call before return the value, but still it print the //runs first before the //runs after

Comment: You can't do this in `numberOfRowsInSecfion` you should do it in a method such as `viewDidLoad` and call `reloadData` on the tableview in the completion closure

Comment: @Paulw11 could you explain a bit more on this "reloadData"

Comment: Refer to the tableview documentation and the table view programming guide.

Comment: From the Alamofire readme:  (emphasis added): "Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously. ... Rather than blocking execution to wait for a response from the server, a callback is specified to handle the response once it's received. The result of a request is **only available inside the scope of a response handler.** Any execution contingent on the response or data received from the server **must be done within a handler.**"

Comment: @MartinR ok this seem to be really completed for a starter :-) thanks anyway :(

Comment: @FabianBoulegue: The point is that the request is handled asynchronously and there is no way to get the response synchronously in the numberOfRowsInSection method. Another good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected. This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457385/tableview-reloaddata-is-not-working-swift

Comment: @MartinR ah ok, thanks.
I now tried it with "self.tableView.reloadData()" but the tableview seem to update it self all the time if i scroll is this correct?

Comment: As @Paulw11 said above, you must move the request from numberOfRowsInSection to viewDidLoad so that it is done only once.

Comment: @MartinR ah ok, well then i need to check how to move the "updated" values for the return of numberOfRowsInSection from my viewDidLoad into numberOfRowsInSection again

Comment: The result from the request is already stored in `self.arrRes`! numberOfRowsInSection just needs to return `self.arrRes.count`.